# What is proper way to dispose after getting audit entries?

Tags: powershell, auditing

I'm cleaning up our audit logs exporting to a local disk for archiving. The logs are so big I can only export about a half a month at a time. The script I wrote works fine, but I'd like to automate the entire process for every month.

This command causes about 1.5gb to 3gb of memory to be used.

```
$site.Audit.GetEntries($query) > $outputFile
```

Currently, I have to close powershell and rerun the script for each month to free up memory on the server.

I've tried `$site.dispose()`, but this hasn't freed up any memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a script `callAuditExport.ps1` that calls your current script file like this

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file C:\MyScript.ps1", "Arg1", "Arg2"
```

This will cause a new Powershell process to run, then close when its done executing.  It should free up the memory allocation when its done that way.

Comment: This works great. In addition, adding `-wait` will ensure the process finishes before continuing with the rest of the calling script. This is great because now I can chain these commands and let it to the heavy lifting instead of constantly monitoring for completion. Great answer!